# jquery object, merge duplicate value as array

Tags: jquery

I have an array of object with duplicate name object (here "Letter").
I need to merge objects named "Letter" as an array of the Values.

How can I manage it with jquery ?

FYI, the object come from a form "$(form).serializeArray()" with mutiple option in select

Original :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Hello",
        "value": "World"
    },
    {
        "name": "Letter",
        "value": "A"
    },
    {
        "name": "Letter",
        "value": "B"
    }
]
```

Expected :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Hello",
        "value": "World"
    },
    {
        "name": "Letter",
        "value": [
            "A",
            "B"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a minor tweek for you

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Hello",
    "value": "World"
  },
  {
    "name": "Letter",
    "value": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Letter",
    "value": "B"
  }
];

const result = Array.from(new Set(data.map(s => s.name)))
  .map(item => {
    return {
      name: item,
      value: data.filter(s => s.name === item).map(x => x.value).length === 1 ? data.filter(s => s.name === item).map(x => x.value)[0] : data.filter(s => s.name === item).map(x => x.value)
    }
  })

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is this better ?

Comment: Thanks it is perferct !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your after

```js
var data = [
    {
        "name": "Hello",
        "value": "World"
    },
    {
        "name": "Letter",
        "value": "A"
    },
    {
        "name": "Letter",
        "value": "B"
    }
];

const result = Array.from(new Set(data.map(s => s.name)))
    .map(item => {
      return {
        name: item,
        value: data.filter(s => s.name === item).map(x => x.value)
      }
    })

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it helps but it return "World" as an array, and I need to have that one as string. Only duplicate must be array, the rest need to stay like it was. Any advices ?

Comment: I did that but not sure it the best ?

`code`
 const array = Array.from(new Set(data.map(s => s.name)))
        .map(item => {
            if ((data.filter(s => s.name === item)).length > 1) {

                return {
                    name: item,
                    value: data.filter(s => s.name === item).map(x => x.value)
                }

            }

            return {
                name: item,
                value: (data.filter(s => s.name === item))[0]['value']
            }

        })

Comment: yes that's fine, I posted an update for you that will do the same thing but a more compact version